# SemanticUi css firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, semantic-ui

In firefox SemanticUI javascript calculations of sticky did not work correctly. We have table that header `td`'s use sticky and in all browsers work fine except Firefox. After first element all td-s are on top of another. Generated from javascript css did not calculated propery. See difference between chrome and firefox -

Link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aduew9uo/)

```
<table class="ui cellled striped table" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asddd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdda</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdddd</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
$( '#table tbody tr td' ).click(function() {
  $( "#table .ui.sticky" ).sticky('refresh');
});
```